# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing -Python

Tags: python, eof

I am using the concept of priority scheduling to create a program that should take two inputs,  number of incoming packets, and the priority string for the incoming packets. For example, for input “4” and “HLHH'', the order of outgoing packets should be ``0 2 1 3''.

When i run the program i keep getting this error:

```
Input:4 HLHH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schedule.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "schedule.py", line 62, in main
    inputStr=input("Input:")
  File "<string>", line 1
    4 HLHH
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Here is my source code :

```
import re

#Used to set the priorities for initial buffer
def setPriorityForBuffer(priorityStr,priorityList):
    counter=0
    outgoingPkt=[]
    #Set priority for H first
    for i in range(0,3):
        if priorityStr[i]=='H':
            outgoingPkt.append(priorityList[counter])
            counter+=1
        else:
            outgoingPkt.append('NA')
    #Set priority for L next
    for i in range(0,3):
        if outgoingPkt[i]=='NA':
            outgoingPkt[i]=priorityList[counter]
            counter+=1
    return outgoingPkt

def getPriority(numPackets,priorityStr):
    outputStr = " " 
    outgoingPkt=[]
    priorityList=[]
    for i in range(0,numPackets):
        priorityList.append(str(i))
    if numPackets<=0:
        return 'Wrong input: the number of packets must be greater than 0.'
    elif numPackets!=len(priorityStr):
        return 'Wrong input: the number of packets is wrong.'
    else:
        pattern = re.compile('^[LH]+$')
        if not re.search(pattern, priorityStr):
            return 'Wrong input: the priority must be H or L'
        if numPackets==3:
            outgoingPkt=setPriorityForBuffer(priorityStr,priorityList)
        elif numPackets>3:
            #For first 3 packets
            outgoingPkt=setPriorityForBuffer(priorityStr,priorityList)
            #For remaining packets
            counter=3
            #Set priority for H first
            for i in range(3,len(priorityStr)):
                if priorityStr[i]=='H':
                    outgoingPkt.append(priorityList[counter])
                    counter+=1
                else:
                    outgoingPkt.append('NA')
            #Set priority for L next
            for i in range(3,len(priorityStr)):
                if outgoingPkt[i]=='NA':
                    outgoingPkt[i]=priorityList[counter]
                    counter+=1
                    
        for i in outgoingPkt:
            outputStr=outputStr+i+" "
            
    return outputStr
                    
def main():
    #Get input from user
    inputStr=input("Input:")
    inputList=inputStr.split(" ")
    numPackets=int(inputList[0])
    priorityStr=inputList[1]
    #Call function and print outgoingpacket string
    print("Output:",getPriority(numPackets,priorityStr))
    

#Driver code
main()
```

any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Which python are you using? This looks like the `input` function from the old python 2.x that tried to evaluate input.

Comment: As a note on debugging and asking questions here on stackoverflow, once an error hints, later code is irrelevant. Your problem is in one of the first lines executed. You could reproduce this with just a few lines code. That makes it easier for everybody to see what is going on.

Comment: Just before calling `main`, you could `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: Hello, I am using python 3.10

Comment: What was the exact string returned by `print(sys.version)`?

Comment: this: 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 19 2020, 20:48:48)  ?

Comment: I ran the code with version 3.11 it completed without an error. `Input:4 HLHH
Output:  0 2 1 3 `. " For example, for input “4” and “HLHH'', the order of outgoing packets should be ``0 2 1 3''

Comment: were you able to get the expected output ?

Comment: You are getting python 2.7, not python 3.10 when you run. So this is a question about how you execute the script and how your system is setup. I suggest a much smaller test script (just import sys and print) to debug that.

Comment: Let us know which operating system you are on and how you run the script. Suppose you are doing `python myscript.py` , then it may be as simple as `python3 myscript.py`.

Comment: Okay i think i got it now. I was running on VS code but when i ran the script through terminal it was set to python 2.7. I switched it to 3.10 and is now working, thanks guys